# SpongyCastle: how to generate signed data?

Tags: android, android-studio, x509certificate, sha1, spongycastle

I have a message and I want to sign that data with a digital certificate, in ANDROID, with android-studio. This my code:

```html
List certList = new ArrayList();
                //CMSTypedData     msg = new CMSProcessableByteArray("Hello world!".getBytes());
                certList.add(pCertificate);
                Store certs = new JcaCertStore(certList);
                CMSSignedDataGenerator gen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
                ContentSigner sha1Signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder(gen.DIGEST_SHA1).setProvider("SC").build((PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey(alias, "zara2008".toCharArray()));

                gen.addSignerInfoGenerator(
                        new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(
                                new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().setProvider("SC").build())
                                .build(sha1Signer, pCertificate));

                gen.addCertificates(certs );
                // Add the data (XML) to the Message
                String dstdn = "cn=wsaahomo,o=afip,c=ar,serialNumber=CUIT 33693450239";
                String LoginTicketRequest_xml;
                LoginTicketRequest_xml = LoginTicket.create_LoginTicketRequest(SignerDN, dstdn, "wsfe", (long) 3600);
                CMSProcessable data = new CMSProcessableByteArray(LoginTicketRequest_xml.getBytes());
                CMSTypedData datatyped = new CMSProcessableByteArray(LoginTicketRequest_xml.getBytes());
                CMSSignedData sigData = gen.generate(datatyped, false);
```

This is the error:
"Unknown signature type requested: 1.3.14.3.2.26"

### I tryed distints solutions, like put "DIGEST_SHA1" but doesn't works.

I tryed with BouncyCastle in ANDROID (I run some script that I found elsewhere that makes that BC works in Android).
It's gives me a lot of messages "deprecated".

```html
 // Create a new empty CMS Message
            CMSSignedDataGenerator gen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();

            // Add a Signer to the Message
            gen.addSigner(pKey, pCertificate, CMSSignedDataGenerator.DIGEST_SHA1);

            // Add the Certificate to the Message
            gen.addCertificatesAndCRLs(cstore);

            // Add the data (XML) to the Message
            CMSProcessable data = new CMSProcessableByteArray(LoginTicketRequest_xml.getBytes());

            // Add a Sign of the Data to the Message
            CMSSignedData signed = gen.generate(data, true, "BC");

            //
            asn1_cms = signed.getEncoded();
```

But this is not a solution, I dont want to work with deprecated code.

Comment: Cesar, pudiste armar lo que AFIP denomina CMS del tipo “SignedData”?
Generé el TRA y la firma del TRA pero no tengo idea de como mandarlo en loginCms.

Comment: Si, me pude conectar a la AFIP y obtener el ticket de autorización. Usé las mismas librerías que se usan en el ejemplo que te da la AFIP. Las descargué y las agregué al proyecto y las usé. En un rato me fijo cómo lo hice.

Comment: Los Jar son: bcmail, bcprov, y ksoap2-android-assembly.

Comment: dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/bcmail2.jar')
    compile files('libs/bcprov2.jar')
    compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.3.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
}

Comment: la llamada al ws de la AFIP la hice con la librería ksoap2

Comment: Mi email es cesjavi at gmail dot com. pasame el tuyo y te paso el código que usé.

Answer (score 0):

Afip don't have support for Android Connection. Try with wcf service and the certified installed in the server.

Comment: Amigo no estoy preguntando si afip tiene soporte para Android. Releé que ahi puse que me pude conectar a la AFIP pero usando librerías que están obsoletas.

Comment: I'm not asking if AFIP has support for Android . Please read the post 3 or 4 times until you can understand THAT I CONNECT SUCCESFULLY WITH AFIP BUT WITH OBSOLETES LIBRARIES.